# html element not responding to positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

I can't get the img element to move to the left hand side. The left: 0px attribute isn't doing anything. In fact, I can't seem to move anything inside the #top div to move.

The img tag is inside top. I omitted rest of the webpage but I hope this is enough.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="topBorder">&nbsp;</div>

    <div id="top">
        <img src="logo.png" style="width:50%; height: 20%; left: 2em"/>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
max-width: 60em;
margin: auto;
position: relative;

}

div {
border: solid;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 1em;
margin-bottom: 1em;

}

#topBorder {

background-color:#255FAA;
height: .7em;
width: 100%;
border: transparent;
}

#top {
background-color: white;
border: transparent;
height: 13%;
width: 100%;
font-family: Georgia, Palatino Linotype; 

}


#top img{
border: solid black;
position: relative;
left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `text-align:center` from your `div` element is the problem.  Try overriding that in `#top` and I think it will start behaving as you expect.  See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3KyrW/

Comment: Nice catch ... I missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

Your `#top` should have `positive: relative`, then your `#top img` should have `position: absolute` ... that will move the image around in your header.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure about what how are trying to position.  But adding a `display: block;` and a `float: left;` to `#top img` seems to float the image to the left. The `left: 0px;` is not needed when using `position: relative;` so I removed it. Also added a `position: relative;` to the `#top` `<div>`.

Also you seem to have inline styles in your `<img>` tag?  That seems off.

```
<img src="logo.png" style="width:50%; height: 20%; left: 2em"/>
```

So I took that out & added it to the CSS as well. New `<img>` tag looks like this:

Revised CSS is here:

```
#top {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border: transparent;
    height: 13%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Georgia, Palatino Linotype; 
}


#top img{
    border: solid black;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20%;
    left: 2em;
}
```